# How to know the percentage of occurence of a value in a raster in R?

Tags: r, raster

If have a raster `r`:

```
 r <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10)
values(r) <- runif(ncell(r))
```

Now I would like to know how much (in percent) the value `0.5` occurs in this raster in comparison to the others(in other words how many pixels that contain this value among all pixels of this raster)

thanks

Comment: Do you mean a value of at least 0.5 or some such? With `runif()`, you'll nearly never get a value that's exactly equal to 0.5000000000...

Comment: Try `sum(r[]==2)/length(r)`

Comment: @nicola -- Yep. Do you happen to know what's best if the raster is too large to hold all of its values in memory?

Comment: `sum(values(r)==2, na.rm=TRUE)/length(r)`

Comment: So exclude them yourself if you want to. You should have know how to do it at this time: `sum(r[]==2,na.rm=TRUE)/sum(!is.na(r[]))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've taken the liberty to use different sample data as your comment indicated that you are not interested in continuous data.

```
values(r) <- rpois(ncell(r),3)
```

You can convert your raster to a vector by using as.vector, and then tabulate this and find the proportions of each element. `table` ignores NA values. Here I select the proportion of values that are equal to 2.

```
prop.table(table(as.vector(r)))["2"]
   2 
0.19
```

Note that 2 is used as a string as it is a label for the vector.

Comment: It's interesting that `table(as.vector(r))` is considerably faster than `raster::freq(r)`.